# How do I slice a line from a text file in python?

Tags: python, string, text-files, slice

Currently I am working on a python password manager. Its not too complex, just a simple commandline interface. I have made one file in which the passwords and usernames are stored in the following format:

```
servicenameusername-usernameinput
servicenamepassword-generatedpassword
```

for eg:

```
GOOGLEusername-myusername
GOOGLEpassword-generated password
```

The problem is that when I try to fetch the password and username from a separate program. I need a way to slice a line in the txt file.
eg:

```
GOOGLEpassword-passowrd
GOOGLEusername-username
```

I want the program to get the service name as input and then return what is in front of them. I need to slice it in such a way that it takes the first character of the password and prints it until the line ends. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using a structured format like JSON? And of cause encryption would be a good idea.

Comment: its a local file only project. i dont need any encryption. and i also dont know anything in java. im a beginner

Comment: To make sure I understand the question correctly >>> From `GOOGLEusername-myusername` you want to get `myusername`

Comment: yes that is the problem. and the `myusername` is of variable length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some `string.split()` magic will resolve this. I added some logic to be able to deal with usernames or passwords containing the `-` character

**password.py**

```py
from pprint import pprint


def process_two_lines(line1: str, line2: str) -> dict:
    # determine which of the 2 variables is the password
    # and which is the username
    if 'password' in line1.split('-')[0]:
        passwordline = line1
        userline = line2
    else:
        passwordline = line2
        userline = line1
    
    # the join is in case the password or username contains a "-" character
    password = '-'.join(passwordline.split('-')[1:]).strip('\n') 
    username = '-'.join(userline.split('-')[1:]).strip('\n')
    service = userline.split('username')[0]
    return {
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
        'service':  service
    }    


def get_login_info(filename: str) -> dict:
    # read file
    with open(filename) as infile:
        filecontents = infile.readlines()
    
    result = []
    # go through lines by pair
    for index, line1 in enumerate(filecontents[::2]):
        result.append(process_two_lines(line1, filecontents[(index*2)+1]))

    return result



logininfo = get_login_info('test1.txt')
pprint(logininfo)
print('----------\n\n')

for index, line in enumerate(logininfo):
    print(f'{index:2}: {line["service"]}')


service = int(input('Please select the service for which you want the username/password:\n'))

print(f'Username:\n{logininfo[service]["username"]}\nPassword:\n{logininfo[service]["password"]}\n')
```

**test1.txt**

```
TESTACCOUNTusername-test-user
TESTACCOUNTpassword-0R/bL----d?>[G
GOOGLEusername-google
GOOGLEpassword-V*biw:Y<%6k`?JI)r}tC
STACKOVERFLOWusername-testing
STACKOVERFLOWpassword-5AmT-S)My;>3lh"
```

**output**

```
[{'password': '0R/bL----d?>[G',
  'service': 'TESTACCOUNT',
  'username': 'test-user'},
 {'password': 'V*biw:Y<%6k`?JI)r}tC',
  'service': 'GOOGLE',
  'username': 'google'},
 {'password': '5AmT-S)My;>3lh"',
  'service': 'STACKOVERFLOW',
  'username': 'testing'}]
----------


 0: TESTACCOUNT
 1: GOOGLE
 2: STACKOVERFLOW
Please select the service for which you want the username/password:
2
Username:
testing
Password:
5AmT-S)My;>3lh"
```

### Original answer

**password.py**

```py
from pprint import pprint

def get_login_info(filename: str) -> dict:
    with open(filename) as infile:
        filecontents = infile.readlines()
    for line in filecontents:
        if 'password' in line.split('-')[0]: # split needed to not get false positive if username == password
            password = line.split('-')[1].strip('\n') # gets the part after the - separator, removing the newline
            service = line.split('password')[0] # gets the service part
        elif 'username' in line.split('-')[0]: # split needed to not get false positive if password == username
            username = line.split('-')[1].strip('\n')
    result = {
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
        'service':  service
    }    
    return result

pprint(get_login_info('test0.txt'))
pprint(get_login_info('test1.txt'))
```

**output:**

```py
{'password': 'generatedpassword',
 'service': 'servicename',
 'username': 'usernameinput'}
{'password': 'generated password',
 'service': 'GOOGLE',
 'username': 'myusername'}
```

Comment: thank you for the help. but it returns only one password, service and username. Whereas there will be many services and passwords in the text file. Please suggest something in which we take input from user for which password they want and return the specific username, password and service. thank you once again

Comment: @thefoodiee please provide a multiple services and passwords case file pattern.

Comment: @leaf_yakitori here is the sample data in correct form: (https://pastebin.com/GNGT1Vy6)

Comment: @thefoodiee answer updated accordingly. Please provide exact data sample and exact question next time. Remember, the better your question, the better the answer